# RichTextBox.append with font color?

Tags: vb.net, fonts, colors, richtextbox

I need to set the color of the font every time I add text to the RichTextBox

I'm using..

```
RtbResults.AppendText(DisplayPacket)
```

To add a new line of text, but each line needs to be a set color.
I found this on the net but it doesn't seem to work in my VS11b

```
RtbResults.AppendText(DisplayPacket,forecolor,backcolor,font)
```

Are these the correct overloads? can I do this another way if this doesn't work?
I don't want to have to insert the text then go back and select and change its color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SelectionColor property, like this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
var oldcolor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.AppendText("foo");
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = oldcolor;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, How efficient is this method? I am working on a small Packet Sniffer and I will be adding lots of lines in various colors. will it still run if the rtb has lots of data building up. thank you.

Comment: In general, "adding lots of lines" is always a bottleneck.  Be sure to delete lines so you stay well below a megabyte of text.  You could surely bypass the SelectionStart assignment in your specific scenario, changing the SelectionColor costs very little.