# Changing Font Color RTF

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox

```
foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
{
   RichTextBox rtf = new RichTextBox();
   string[] s = rtf.Lines;

   richTextBox1.Text += b.ToString() + s.ToString() + "\r\n";
   button1.BackColor = b;
   Application.DoEvents();
   Thread.Sleep(10);        
}
```

Greetings everyone,

I have a sequence going through all the KnownColors, changing the button's color and writing the name of each color in the RTF, each in it's own line. Now I wish to change the font color of each line to match the name of the color in each line.

Cheers, N

Comment: possible duplicate of [RichTextBox.append with font color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109113/richtextbox-append-with-font-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out...

```
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = b;
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = b.ToString() + "\r\n";
            button1.BackColor = b;
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
```

Comment: Great job! Thanks :) .Selection :)

Comment: I knew i was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
    {
       RichTextBox rtf = new RichTextBox();
       string[] s = rtf.Lines;

       richTextBox1.Text += b.ToString() + s.ToString() + "\r\n";
       richTextBox1.SelectionColor = b;
       button1.BackColor = b;
       Application.DoEvents();
       Thread.Sleep(10);        
    }
```

Comment: That just colors all the text to the same color, I've tried that already

Comment: Whenever you set the Text() property you'll lose all previous formatting.